# Script for converting intermingled cell data to interaction matix

Tags: excel, vba

I have bibliographic data from Web of Science that I need to configure into an interaction matrix (basically a tabulation table of authors working together). However, the cells are configured awkwardly.

```
1: [Hussain, Raja Azadar; Badshah, Amin] Quaid I Azam Univ, Dept Chem, Coordinat Chem Lab, Islamabad, Pakistan; [Tahir, Muhammad Nawaz] Univ Sargodha, Dept Phys, Sargodha, Punjab, Pakistan; [Tamoor-ul- Hassan; Bano, Asghari] Quaid I Azam Univ, Phytoharmone Lab, Dept Plant Sci, Islamabad, Pakistan
2: [Shahida, Shabnam; Khan, Muhammad Haleem] Univ Azad Jammu & Kashmir, Dept Chem, Muzaffarabad, Ajk, Pakistan; [Ali, Akbar] Pakistan Inst Nucl Sci & Technol, Div Chem, Islamabad, Pakistan
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
1: Hussain, Raja Azadar, Quaid I Azam Univ, Dept Chem, Coordinat Chem Lab, Islamabad, Pakistan
1: Badshah, Amin, Quaid I Azam Univ, Dept Chem, Coordinat Chem Lab, Islamabad, Pakistan
1: Tamoor-ul- Hassan, Quaid I Azam Univ, Phytoharmone Lab, Dept Plant Sci, Islamabad, Pakistan
1: Bano, Asghari, Quaid I Azam Univ, Phytoharmone Lab, Dept Plant Sci, Islamabad, Pakistan
2: Shahida, Shabnam, Univ Azad Jammu & Kashmir, Dept Chem, Muzaffarabad, Ajk, Pakistan
2: Khan, Muhammad Haleem, Univ Azad Jammu & Kashmir, Dept Chem, Muzaffarabad, Ajk, Pakistan
2: Ali, Akbar, Pakistan Inst Nucl Sci & Technol, Div Chem, Islamabad, Pakistan
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Split on `; [` --> arr1
    For each element in arr1:
        Split on `]` --> arr2(0) and arr2(1)
            split arr2(0) on `;` -->arr3
                 For each element in arr3:
                      Combine arr3(x) with arr2(1) - put in cell
Loop till done
```

Comment: OK. Not working out for me as a new module. I'll try to play with it a bit though.

Comment: Edited my pseudocode - first split delimiter was wrong